# Any way to remove "confirm" of Like button due to testing during Facebook's buggy Like button period?

Tags: facebook-like

Yesterday, I was testing a newly implemented "Like" button on my website, but noticed that the like box was not displaying properly. I wasn't sure if it was on my end, so I did a lot of changes and testing, and finally found out that it was a bug on Facebook's end. But due to the repeatedly failed testing pressing of the button during this buggy period, my Like box now needs to go through the "confirm" phase.

I was wondering if there's any way to notify facebook or any other known way to remove the confirm phase? It's extremely frustrating to first not have the code work properly, then have it lock me out as I tried to test my code during their buggy period.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the target URL to something else, for example,

from:
http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=YOU-WEBSITE-URL

to:
http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.google.com

until you're done testing, then change the URL back.